# How to make wicket's quickstart maven archetype for 1.4.9 available in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, wicket, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 with the m2Eclipse plugin. Up until now I've been using Wicket's web based quickstart, but I just realised that m2Eclipse allows me to create Maven projects from archetypes within Eclipse.

The problem is that the wicket-archetype-quickstart is version 1.4.7, but the newest version of Wicket is 1.4.9. Is it possible to make the 1.4.9 version of the wicket quickstart archetype available to m2eclipse? And better yet, is there an archetype for Wicket+Spring+Hibernate(and JPA)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wicket + Spring + JPA archetype with sample application (uses Wicket 1.4.9)](http://jweekend.com/dev/LegUp)

To adjust your version of Wicket, just edit the POM file's Wicket depending version.

To use this archetype in Eclipse, I did the following: ran maven at the command line to generate a project from the archetype:

```
    mvn archetype:generate -B  \ 
   -DarchetypeCatalog=http://legup.googlecode.com/svn/repo/archetype-catalog.xml \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-spring-jpa-archetype \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=com.jweekend -DarchetypeVersion=0.8.3 \
   -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=mycompany \
   -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany
```

Cd'd into the project directory, ran `mvn jetty_run` to download dependencies, build, and run the app.

Ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate eclipse metadata.

In Eclipse, File| New project | "from existing source" to import it.